# How can I uninstall Opera from Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, opera

I have downloaded opera from the website (deb package) and installed it. Now I want to remove it but I don't know how. I tried `sudo apt-get remove opera` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 26):

@Thomas W.'s answer didn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04. I had to use:

```
sudo dpkg -r opera-stable
```

And to remove the apt sources file added by Opera:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list
```

Comment: What about /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opera-stable.list.save file? Should I remove that also? Isn't there a command that remove all files related to the application, for example sudo apt purge?

Answer (score 10):

When you install via the downloaded .deb binaries/installer and not the opera repository for Opera, then it was installed with `dpkg`, and not `apt-get`.

Try using `sudo dpkg --remove opera` or `sudo dpkg -r opera` to remove it.

Comment: You're welcome, @user159082!  Don't forget to mark this as accepted if it helped!

Comment: Or equally use: `sudo dpkg -r opera`

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge opera-stable
```

Try this, it's gonna work.

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1113681/

Comment: Although this is not the same as [that earlier answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113681/22949), since this also removes conffiles (due to `--purge`), it's not obvious how the difference is important or why this approach is more likely to help, or otherwise better, than that one. You may want to [edit] this to clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
dpkg -l | grep opera
```

to find out proper package name. For me opera-stable then

```
sudo apt-get remove opera-stable
```