# Can't run a .sh file even when changing directory

Tags: scripts, expect

I want to know how to excute a .sh file. I have tried to change the directory as (Wi-fEye-v0.5.6/bin$) and run `./filename.sh` but it said:

```
bash: ./evilgrade.sh: /usr/bin/expect: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Close-voters, this question is about "Running third-party applications on Ubuntu", so it is [on-topic](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: user159082, please don't forget to mark answers as accepted when you get an answer that works for you. You've got [an answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/296021/65926) to another question that wasn't accepted. Read the [about](http://askubuntu.com/about) page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install **expect**. In a terminal window, run:

```
sudo apt-get install expect
```